# Stopword removal with NLTK and Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, nltk, stop-words

I have some issues with Pandas and NLTK. I am new at programming, so excuse me if i ask questions that might be easy to solve. I have a csv file which has 3 columns(Id,Title,Body) and about 15.000 rows.

My goal is to remove the stopwords from this csv file. The operation for lowercase and split are working well. But i can not find my mistake why the stopwords does not get removed. What am i missing?

```
    import pandas as pd
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords

    pd.read_csv("test10in.csv", encoding="utf-8") 

    df = pd.read_csv("test10in.csv") 

    df.columns = ['Id','Title','Body']
    df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.lower().str.split()  
    df['Body'] = df['Body'].str.lower().str.split() 


    stop = stopwords.words('english')

    df['Title'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
    df['Body'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])

    df.to_csv("test10out.csv")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you are trying to do an inplace replace. you should do

```
   df['Title'] = df['Title'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
    df['Body'] = df['Body'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My lack of programming experience i guess :)  you are the hero of the day.

Comment: you're welcome. I recently started using nltk for text processing and so i have myself made these mistakes :) glad to help. also, check out Kaggle.com for some cool introductory tutorials on text analytics. all the best :)

Answer (score -2):

```
df.replace(stop,regex=True,inplace=True)
```